# Getting Input from Radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a mix of Tkinter and graphics.py (a wrapper on Tkinter) to create a fairly basic integrator (find the area under a graph) with a GUI. As of now, the main "control panel" for the integrator is separate from the actual graph (which is made by using graphics.py). I am using Tkinter's `Radiobutton()` for the choice selection of the integration type (Left Rectangular, Right Rectangular, Trapezoidal, or Simpson's Approximation).

My problem is that I am unable to get the output from the radiobuttons. I was using the example from [TutorialsPoint: Tkinter Radiobutton](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm).

Here is my code:

```
class FunctionInput:
        def __init__(self, master, window, items):
            self.window = window
            self.items = items
            self.runProgram = True
            self.typeChoice = tk.StringVar()
            self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
            self.typeFrame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
            self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', command = self.frame.quit)
            self.optLabel = tk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Type of Approximation: ')
            self.optL = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = 'Left Rectangular', variable = self.typeChoice, value = 'l')
            self.optR = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = 'Right Rectangular', variable = self.typeChoice, value = 'r')
            self.optT = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = 'Trapezoidal', variable = self.typeChoice, value = 't')
            self.optS = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = 'Simpsons Rule', variable = self.typeChoice, value = 's')
            self.optL.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            self.optR.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            self.optT.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            self.optS.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            self.optLabel.grid(row = 4)
            self.typeFrame.grid(row = 5)
            self.quitButton.grid(row = 6)
            # there were numerous other widgets and frames, but I only included the relevant ones
            self.frame.grid()

        def getInput(self):
            type_integration = self.typeChoice.get()
            self.frame.quit()
            return type_integration


def main():
    # some other code, win and axisLabels are defined prior to this
    root = tk.Tk(className = ' Function Grapher')
    app = FunctionInput(root, win, axisLabels)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    root.mainloop() # there is a button to exit the mainloop in my GUI
    typeIntegration = app.getInput()
    print typeIntegration # trying to debug it

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

However, it doesn't not print the variable. It prints an empty string, so execution is not a problem. `root.mainloop()` does not get stuck in an infinite loop, because I have a button in my GUI (not shown here because it is irrelevant) that exits it. An error is not raised, so I'm guessing that the issue is with setting the option to the variable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, on a side note, whenever I run the program, the 'Right Rectangular', 'Trapezoidal', and 'Simpson's Rule' radiobuttons are grayed out, like such:

[image]

This grayness goes away if I click on one of the radiobuttons, but until then, it stays. If there is some way to fix this, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that since I was using multiple other widgets, I had to set `StringVar()`s `master` parameter as `self.typeFrame`:

```
class FunctionInput:
        def __init__(self, master, window, items):
            self.window = window
            self.items = items
            self.runProgram = True
            self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
            self.typeFrame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
            self.typeChoice = tk.StringVar(self.typeFrame)
            self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', command = self.frame.quit)
            self.optLabel = tk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Type of Approximation: ')
            self.optL = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = 'Left Rectangular', variable = self.typeChoice, value = 'l')
            self.optR = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = 'Right Rectangular', variable = self.typeChoice, value = 'r')
            self.optT = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = 'Trapezoidal', variable = self.typeChoice, value = 't')
            self.optS = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = 'Simpsons Rule', variable = self.typeChoice, value = 's')
            self.optL.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            self.optR.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            self.optT.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            self.optS.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            self.optLabel.grid(row = 4)
            self.typeFrame.grid(row = 5)
            self.quitButton.grid(row = 6)
            # there were numerous other widgets and frames, but I only included the relevant ones
            self.frame.grid()

        def getInput(self):
            type_integration = self.typeChoice.get()
            self.frame.quit()
            return type_integration


def main():
    # some other code, win and axisLabels are defined prior to this
    root = tk.Tk(className = ' Function Grapher')
    app = FunctionInput(root, win, axisLabels)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    root.mainloop() # there is a button to exit the mainloop in my GUI
    print app.getInput()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Also, as @A. Rodas said, to get rid of the grayness, I did:

```
self.typeFrame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
self.typeChoice = tk.StringVar(self.typeFrame)
self.typeChoice.set(None)
```

Comment: Since this answer provides the real solution to your problem, I encourage you to accept this answer instead of mine's.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the part of the exit button, but your code does something like this:

1. Starts the mainloop
2. The event handler of the exit button calls `root.quit()`
3. In `getInput`, retrieves the value and calls `self.frame.quit()`

Calling Tkinter functions after the mainloop may lead to problems like this, so you should get the value of the StringVar first and then exit the GUI loop. This is a working example based on your code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.type_integration = None
        self.typeChoice = tk.StringVar()
        self.typeChoice.set(None) # This fixes the grayness of the radio buttons!
        self.typeFrame = tk.Frame(master)
        OPTIONS = [('Left Rectangular', 'l'),
                   ('Right Rectangular', 'r'),
                   ('Trapezoidal', 't'),
                   ('Simpsons Rule', 's')]
        for text, value in OPTIONS:
            tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text=text, variable=self.typeChoice, value=value).pack()
        tk.Button(self.typeFrame, text="Exit", command=self.exit).pack()
        self.typeFrame.pack()
    def exit(self):
        self.type_integration = self.typeChoice.get()
        self.master.destroy() # self.master.quit() freezes the GUI
    def getinput(self):
        return self.type_integration

master = tk.Tk()
app = App(master)
tk.mainloop()
print app.getinput()
```

Comment: It wasn't the problem with setting the variables, because I have about 6 other widgets (a mix of `Entry`s and `Slide`s), which also get input from the user, and I was using the same function to get the input. Those values were printed, but `type_integration` always printed as `''`'. Also, I changed my structure to follow yours (the exit button sets the variables) and tried to print the variables from the exit button: all variables except `type_integration` printed correctly.

Comment: Oh! I figured out what was wrong. I had to create `StringVar` with the master option set as `self.typeFrame` because I have numerous other frames in one master frame.